# What input is used when openssl creates digest for a file?

Tags: hash, openssl, sha256, sha

When I type

`openssl sha256 filename.pdf`

What value is used to create a digest? Is it a meta data of that file or every byte data of that pdf? I tried openssl sha256 on a large files(~2GB) and it did not take a long time, so my guess is that openssl does not use every byte in a file. So what value(byte) is used?

Comment: This is not about programming or development and thus is offtopic, but it is every byte of the file, and nothing outside the file (i.e. NOT the filename, timestamp, permissions/ACL, etc). Modern systems can hash 2GB in about a second or less, and read it in only a few seconds worst case (real disk not SSD and not cached). You can confirm this by `cat filename.pdf | openssl sha256` (on Windows use `type` instead) which provides `openssl` _only_ the contents of the file.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! If I may, I have additional question. I downloaded foo.zip file and created a digest for that file. Later, I unzipped foo.zip and re-zipped that file without making any modifications, but digest was different. What could be the reason?

Comment: The internal dates in the new foo.zip would be different, for a start. You should have made a digest for the unzipped contents, not the .zip file.

Comment: (1) the deflate algorithm has many options, which different zip-creating programs, or even different uses of the same program, may exercise differently; there are a nearly infinite number of different compressed forms for the same 'real' data (2) zip format includes metadata which may be different; some 'directory' (aka header) fields can have different values, or be added or removed. However, note the zip metadata includes a CRC32 of the contents before compression (or after decompression); _that_ should not change for the same data.